# Electric flux through an equilateral triangle

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, electric-fields, gauss-law

[image]

There is an equilateral triangle of side length $x$ and at a distance $y$ from the center of the surface,resides a charge $q$. What is the electric flux through that surface?

I tried using gauss law to make a gaussian surface by making a triangular prism. But now i need to determine the flux for the extra $3$ rectangular surfaces also. So it seems this prism idea doesn't help. How can i proceed?